# Automatic update of python code files in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am having a weird problem in Spyder. Namely, whenever I update a code file and run it from the console, it does not compile and apparently Python uses the old pyc file. It gives me the output/errors from the previous compilation.

Even if I delete the `pyc` file from the pycache, to force it to recompile, it does not work. I discovered that restarting the kernel solves this problem, but it takes some time and I am pretty sure that there is a better/quicker way to do this.

I also tried using the autoreload command but it does not work for me.

I'm working on a Windows machine.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) What's your Spyder version? And how are you using `%autoreload`?

Comment: I saw on a forum someone suggested using this:
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2

Comment: Spyder version: Spyder 3.2.4
Python 3.6

Comment: For %autoreload to work, you need to import the module you're working with in the Console.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: That if you writing code in a file named `foo.py`, you need to run `import foo` or `from foo import bar` in the console for `%autoreload` do its magic.

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work.

Comment: Then I don't know what happens, sorry.

Comment: @user1340852 what kind of changes do you perform on the code? `%autoreload` does not work in some situations, see: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html#caveats.